# styling ul with css - why float working like thats

Tags: css, stylesheet

I'am watching some video tutorial about css and find realy strange thing.
First of all we create unordered list with links like elements:

```
<ul id="menuList">
    <li><a href="google.com">This</a></li>
    <li><a href="demo.org">That</a></li>
    <li><a href="pogoda.ru">Other</a></li>
</ul>
```

and than apply some styling to create horizontal menu:

```
#menuList {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menuList a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Thats produce flat menu.
So my question is why is this working? In my opinon float should be applied to **li** element - container. **li** is a block level element or I'm wrong???

Some CSS rules makes me crazy.

Comment: `float`s don't necessarily have to be applied to an element-container, if that was your doubt. `<a>` can very well have a float.

Comment: Actually it's clearer to apply the float to the `li` rather than, specifically, the `a` inside it. Floating can be applied to any element, but it is really only useful when applied to block, non-absolutely-positioned elements. The idea of a container is a subjective one - but yes, containers are often floated.

Comment: But why <li> elements float to each other? Maybe <a> should float inside <li>?

Comment: OK now I see what you're asking. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is not necessarily easy to understand if you're new to CSS.

Your `li` elements are block elements, with no floating. Your `a` elements are inline elements with floating.

The floating of the `a` tag means it no longer gives any signal to the parent `li` as to how tall the `li` should be. In effect, it has been partially lifted out of the vertical stack.

(Side note: this is why it's important to **clear** after floats. If you put a clear element (i.e. an element with `clear: both` applied to it) after each, the effect you currently see would be lost, as the parent `li` would use that clear as a marker for how tall to make itself.)

This means each `li` effectively has zero height, giving the effect that each `a` tag is adjacent to its `a` tag cousins. This is merely a fluke arising form the `li` tags having no height.

This can send people new to CSS somewhat round the twist.

Personally I'd say there's no need in your case to float the `a` tag rather than the `li` (which is what I suggest you do), and would consider it a questionable tutorial for that reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This question should be addressed to floats and layout creating - and how those works.